# HOW do I delete cleverfiles on my Mac?

Tags: mac-mini, recovery

This remains a mystery. In my "About this Mac", I have discovered over 560Gb in my system data. I have gotten a new Mac Mini M2 and need to migrate my files. Now, I've discovered thousands of `.cleverfiles`. Disk Drill support tells me to simply run the uninstall program. Here's the thing, I never downloaded or used DiskDrill. I have no idea where it came from except in 2021 I had a big crash and had to take the computer in for repair. From what I understand, they may have dragged the app into the trash versus actually uninstalling it. (Of course, the tech I spoke with hasn't any idea whether they have ever used this program and 2 years is just so long ago.

I have found the folder in `/System`. I can see all the files. I need to know if I can delete these folders. There are some, they are aliases, that show they were recently used... like two days ago! They are aliases that go to folders on the computer.

If I delete these aliases that point to the folders on the computer, will the contents be deleted?

Another suggestion: Do I download the Disk Drill app and then uninstall it? Will that remove these `.cleverfiles`? I don't want any of these coming over to the new computer. I understand since they are in the systems, if I use the migrate assist and make sure the system isn't checked, they won't come... however, I still need to use the 2014 MacMini with some software programs that are INtel=based until I get everything reset.

Can anyone give me a definitive answer about these files? The folder `.hlink` is HUGE. There are aliases in the folder. I don't have the program but it appears something is accessing something somewhere. 99% of the files are from 2021 and earlier. PS I cannot create `.cleverfiles` or Disk Drill tags since I'm not a 300.

Comment: If you have this folder on your machine, Disk Drill was used.  The “tech” you were working with likely used Disk Drill and then removed it (incompletely).  Why not follow the Disk Drill support person’s advice, to download Disk Drill then uninstall properly?

Comment: When the Time Machine b/u finally finishes (I've had to start it about a dozen times, and after a couple brown outs), I plan on doing that. Only 5 hrs left according to TM. Incremental b/u supposedly.

Comment: I decided to download the Disk Drill app as the tech suggested. I read the "how to uninstall" instructions. I start the process. A heretofore unmentioned popup shows up: Clear Protected Data. Yes or No. No mention in the instructions, not mentioned in any emails back and forth. What the heck is the correct answer here? Will this clear my HD or just get rid of the .cleverfiles?

Comment: That won’t clear your hard dive.  It will clear that `.cleverfiles` data that it uses for recovery.

Comment: That’s exactly what I want. finally got this to work.  My system data files went from 560gb of a 1TB drive to 38 gb. I now have 845gb of free space.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Go ahead and write up an answer.  Be sure to ping me here in comments (@Allan) so I can send an up vote your way.

Comment: @Allan Is this what you needed to do the upvote?

Comment: Yes.  Just up voted you.  Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 1):

I decided to download the Disk Drill app as the tech suggested. I went through the steps and it appeared nothing happened. I deleted the program and this time answered "no" to the question whether to delete the protected data. I wrote back to Disk Drill and he said, "just go ahead and delete the files then." I tried that (they are hidden in System>Volume) and got a message that one of the files was in use. I tried doing a force delete and that did nothing. I ended up dragging the folder BACK where I started.

I decided to give it a try again, downloaded the program, followed the steps to uninstall, chose "yes" to delete protected data and this time the spinning only lasted about 30 seconds. Lo and behold, the files were gone.

In the process I regained over 500gb on a 1TB in the System Data. The first time probably worked. I just didn't wait long enough for over 6000 files to be deleted.